# Chinese characters sometimes turned to question marks when copied to Windows clipboard, why?

Tags: windows, copy-paste, clipboard

Sometimes, when I copy and paste a piece of text, the Chinese characters in the text would become question marks (I believe they are not garbled, but actual question marks).

I believe this has nothing to do with font or encoding or whatever, since it can happen when I copy and paste within the same application, for example notepad, word etc.

I recorded a video to show this problem, this is so weird that I'm starting to think it's hardware related. but again is it even possible that hardware can cause such issue?

Please [click her for a short 30 second video of me recreating the issue](https://youtu.be/0qKQi-H-lik). Any hint/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should copy to [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download) or a text editor that handles Unicode characters, etc. better and compare the results too when this occurs. I find [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download) very helpful when troubleshooting such issues... not exactly the same issue but sort of.

Comment: @Walmart thanks for the suggestion. But I was using the same steps for the 3 tests I did, I don't think it's related to unicode handling as the 3rd test was ok. Also this problem can happen in any program, IE, Word etc.

Comment: @Walmart I just tried with Notepad++, encountered this problem on the very 1st try. :(

Comment: Are you copying the characters from various locations too or does the source of these change or always stay the same? Typically this issue is related to the application not reading the characters correctly or just a bug with the app that it's copied too/from... I've seen this with web apps before such as well know products like QNXT to custom apps... In Notepad++ go up to encoding with the questions marks or unexpected characters pasted and change to UTF-8, ANSI, etc. and you may find that toggling to one will show the expected characters.

Comment: @Walmart I was working on a Word document. I was doing copy and paste within the same document, and this happened dozens of times.  And what I just did with notepad++ was, I opened 2 new tabs, typed in some Chinese characters in one and tried to copy them to the other tab, and it happened.

Comment: I'm out of ideas... I'm not well versed in troubleshooting issues where the Chinese language is actually used but I thought I'd mention what has helped me with similar sounding type issues in the past at least just in case it helped you. I'm sure someone can help or may know what's going on here.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible on another computer? Maybe you have some program installed, which interferes with the clipboard content?

Comment: @Vlad no it's not happening on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem (but not the same as yours), namely the same question marks scattered around in the buffer (or display) window when I copy Chinese characters on a webpage in Chinese with UTF‑8 character set and pasted into Notepad++.

- I bought a preinstalled window system with the Korean language, but I changed the language setting into English.

I have solved the problem after I changed the language font setting into the Korean font.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

2 things can alter the behavior: the **font** and the **encoding**. If you save in a compatible encoding, all you have to do is make sure that in `Format-->Fonts` you have a compatible font selected.